# change 12:00:00 to 00:00:00 php sql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i have this

```
$time = $db->get_row("SELECT shift,shiftend FROM schedule2");

                    $curHour = $time->shift;
                    $endHour = $time->shiftend;
                    echo $curHour;
                    echo "<br>";
```

Currently this exports curhour as 12:00:00 is it possible to change to 00:00:00

Please let me know

greetings

Glenn

Comment: Since its coming from the db, don't you think it'd make more sense to change this where its being inserted?

Comment: in the DB it shows as 00:00:00 but when i echo it it endsup being 12:00:00

Comment: ah it seems it isn't able to pull the right shift from the db how would i do it so if curhour = 00:35 for example and end is 01:35 how would i make it so its able to get the current time and if its between the 2 times do something

Answer (score 0):

if you want to override the value of database then simply make $curHour="00";